# Get status response (like 400,500)

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using the spring Framework which has the header below:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```

I want to fetch the status code to write my Logger. How do I get the response from restTemplate?

```
public boolean performTransition(String transitionId,String jiraId){

    JiraID id = new JiraID(transitionId);
    JiraTransition transition = new JiraTransition();
    transition.setTransition(id);

    String transitionUrlFormat = String.format(transitionUrl,jiraId);

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    HttpEntity epicEntityRequest = new HttpEntity(transition,createHttpHeaders());

    HttpEntity<String> epicEntityResponse= template.exchange(transitionUrlFormat , HttpMethod.POST, epicEntityRequest, String.class);
    //TODO: verify code 204
    ResponseEntity<String>  responseEntity= (ResponseEntity<String>) epicEntityResponse;
    epicEntityResponse.getBody();
    //System.out.println("LOG" +responseEntity);
   //responseEntity.getStatusCode();
    HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();


    return true;
}
```

Also, I want to check for the response code above 400 I want write log.warning().

Comment: show your code snippet

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question needs more elaboration. Are you meaning something like this:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
int statusCode = response.getStatusCode().value();
```

This gives status code as an int, you can do something like:

```
if(statusCode > 400){
//Log here
}
```

The class `ResponseEntity` can give you the entire HTTP response status code, body and headers.

Ofcourse, you need to initialize `restTemplate`, either using default:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

This uses, default: `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`, or if you want something more configurable you can use: `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` which has many configs, like connection pooling etc, read timeout, connection timeout etc.

Comment: on if conditoin its throwing this errorERR: Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus', 'int'

i'm getting this error and i cannot declare it as int so i changed the variable type to HttpStatus

Comment: You can get int value from statusCode.value();